# Problem with creating a row. If there is, update it. If not, create it

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
INSERT INTO `businesses_stats` 
        (ID, Biz_id, Biz_Date) 
VALUES ((   SELECT `ID` 
            FROM businesses_stats 
            WHERE Biz_id = '1' 
            AND Biz_Date = CURRENT_DATE
        ),'1',CURRENT_DATE) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Biz_Revenue = Biz_Revenue+1000;
```

Does not work. Error #1093.

```sql
INSERT INTO `businesses_stats` (`Biz_id`, `Biz_Date`) 
        SELECT '1', CURDATE() FROM DUAL 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `businesses_stats` 
        WHERE `Biz_id`='1' AND `Biz_Date`= CURDATE() LIMIT 1)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Biz_Revenue = Biz_Revenue+1000;
```

Does not work.

Question:
How to do this, if there is Biz_date = CurDate and Biz_id = 1, then update. Otherwise, create a new one with these parameters. Attention! The Biz_date and Biz_id columns cannot be the same in the same row, but both rows are not unique.

Comment: Tag the appropriate database.

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.

Comment: The solution will vary by DBMS.

Comment: I can, however, say with certainty that this isn't SQL Server, as T-SQL does not use backticks for delimit identifiers.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web based interface for MySQL; it's not an RDBMS. I've tagged [[tag:mysql]], as that is presumably what you are *really* using.

Comment: 2nd query (INSERT .. SELECT) is correct and must work without errors. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=731c3c923ca86c714512aa19e10d0d21

Comment: @Akina, yea, request  is  correct. But it adds 0 rows and never update.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE as code-formatted text.

Comment: I did request. It work. is it correctly? **INSERT INTO businesses_stats (`ID`,`Biz_id`, `Biz_Date`, `Biz_Revenue`)
        SELECT (SELECT `ID` 
            FROM businesses_stats 
            WHERE Biz_id = '1' 
            AND Biz_Date = CURRENT_DATE Limit 1) as ID, '1', CURDATE(), '543'
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Biz_Revenue = Biz_Revenue+543;**

Comment: @Akina please see my request. Is correct? Or can it be redone? ID it Primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `businesses_stats` (`ID`,`Biz_id`, `Biz_Date`, `Biz_Revenue`) 
SELECT (SELECT `ID` FROM businesses_stats WHERE Biz_id = '1' 
AND Biz_Date = CURRENT_DATE Limit 1) as ID, '1', CURDATE(), '1000' FROM DUAL 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Biz_Revenue = Biz_Revenue+1000;
```

My solution is this. It works.
Сan it be redone?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect, simply create a unique index using the expression:

```sql
ALTER TABLE businesses_stats
ADD UNIQUE INDEX ((CASE WHEN Biz_id = '1' THEN 1 END), Biz_Date);
```

then use the query

```sql
INSERT INTO businesses_stats (Biz_id, Biz_Date, Biz_Revenue) 
VALUES ('1', CURRENT_DATE, @Biz_Revenue)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Biz_Revenue = Biz_Revenue + VALUES(Biz_Revenue);
```

or (if `Biz_Revenue` increasing value is a constant)

```sql
INSERT INTO businesses_stats (Biz_id, Biz_Date, Biz_Revenue) 
VALUES ('1', CURRENT_DATE, 1000)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Biz_Revenue = Biz_Revenue + 1000;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc17433d7ad3348a949c48e09f6d2529)

Comment: Nice, snk. But working on mysql 8.0. its not great(

Comment: @МаксимБелый I don't have to guess what your MySQL server version is. If not specified, then we can assume that it is actual. Pay attention - you still haven't specified it. PS. Version 5.7 supports generated columns.